# Is there a way to merge multiple gnome-terminal windows into a single tabbed window?

Tags: gnome, gui, gnome-terminal

From a tabbed gnome-terminal window, it's easy to drag tabs out to live in their own window. Is it possible to do the opposite, to merge two gnome-terminals into a single tabbed window?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. Suggest you look at the [Terminator](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) app instead, which is included in the standard repositories.